# Update web api doesn't receive param?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I tried to call the update web api on Postman but it seems that it doesn't pass the id param to the asp.net core controller (asp.net core 2.0)

```
public class ShoppingCartController : BaseController
{ 
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    [Route("api/ShoppingCart/UpdateShoppingCartItem")]
    public IActionResult UpdateShoppingCartItem(long id)
    {

        return new NoContentResult();
    }
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `[FromBody]`.

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
[Route("api/ShoppingCart/UpdateShoppingCartItem")]
public IActionResult UpdateShoppingCartItem([FromBody]long id)
{
    return new NoContentResult();
}
```

In Postman you must use a simple number.
Replace:

```
{
    "id":87908908
}
```

with

`87908908`

Answer (score 1):

Default behaviour of param parsing: From Url.
Use `[FromBody]` before your method param to let asp parse this param from the Body.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing method UpdateShoppingCartItem to the following:

```
public IActionResult UpdateShoppingCartItem([FromBody] long id)
```

Answer (score 0):

`HttpPut` now accepts the route as parameter, so you can combine your attributes.

```
public class ShoppingCartController : BaseController
{
    [HttpPut("api/ShoppingCart/UpdateShoppingCartItem")]
    public IActionResult UpdateShoppingCartItem(long id)
    {

        return new NoContentResult();
    }
 }
```

The model binder should infer the value of `id` from the body.

Using `[HttpPut("{id}")]` would mean that a put request to `localhost:44342/65465` would be a valid action.